# How to create a minimum bounding polygon for raster layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, extents, polygon-creation

I am looking for a tool, that creates minimum bounding polygons around georeferenced aerial images. I have about 200 of them an redrawing there dimensions by hand would be quit time consuming.

I am working with QGIS 2.14.3. I want the tool not to redraw the bounding box but the valid pixel only.

I allready tried out the deprecated plugin Image boundary (which creates only a bounding box and not even that correctly) and the experimental plugin Image footprint (which crashed after 10 minutes). Is there any alternative to these tools?

Comment: is postgresql / postgis an option for you? [ST_MinConvexHull](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_MinConvexHull.html) does this.

Comment: Yes, I actually wanted to set up the project in PostGIS. I will try this solution.